# Having trouble with getAttribute for a WebElement

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am trying to get the attribute of an element. It was working fine but suddenly it is not. Not sure if I changed something.

**Error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined
```

**Method 1:**

```
async getElementAttribute12(webElement: WebElement, whichAttribute: string): Promise<string> {
        try {
            let attribute = '';
            await webElement.getAttribute(whichAttribute).then(async function(attr) {
                await this.info('attr: ', attr);
                attribute = attr;
            });
            return attribute;
        } catch (error) {
            fail(`Get attribute error. ${error}`);
        }
    }
```

**Method 2:**

After checking if the element is present. I think this will be a better approach. Inputs are welcome.

```
    async getElementAttribute(webElement: WebElement, whichAttribute: string): Promise<string> {
        try {
            let attribute = '';
            if (await browser.isElementPresent(webElement)) {
                await webElement.getAttribute(whichAttribute).then(async function(attr) {
                    await this.info('attr: ', attr);
                    attribute = attr;
                });
                return attribute;
            }

        } catch (error) {
            fail(`Get attribute error. ${error}`);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your `this` refers to the wrong thing, you need to use an arrow function here:

```js
await webElement.getAttribute(whichAttribute).then(async (attr) => {
```

Comment: That totally worked. Thank you so much. What was my mistake here? You were saying about ```this``` Which ```this```? Sorry if I am missing something fundamental.

Comment: You get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined` which naturally points to the `await this.info('attr: ', attr);` and tells you exactly what the problem is, namely that you expected `this` to be the same object as the one where `getElementAttribute` method is defined, but inside of a promise callback `this` is set to `undefined` unless you pin it to lexical scope using `=>` instead of `function`

Comment: That explains. Thank you so much for the prompt answer.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid then and use await?